# Viewport size in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, viewport

I know this has been asked a million times, and there a million answers that are all the same and all wrong. I've been struggling to get the viewport size in javascript, in such a way that it works everywhere.

I've gotten as far as getting it to work on every browser, except Safari on iOS. I've tested with iOS 10,11,12 on several iPhones. This is a version of the most robust method I've come across thus far:

```js
function getViewportSize() {
    return {
        width: Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0),
        height: Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)
    };
}
```

However, `document.documentElement.clientHeight` and `window.innerHeight` on iOS both return the height of the *document*, not the height of the viewport. So if the document is longer, they'll return that. They do (both) return the viewport height as long as the page is shorter than the viewport. In a nutshell, both appear to do `Max(viewport height, document height)`.

I've created a pen that will display every width/height property on every object that is somewhat sensible: https://codepen.io/thany-madeinjapan/pen/xBQwNX Just add more text and you'll see the two properties mentioned will happily grow with the document, i.e. they do not reflect the viewport height. The width has the same problem - disable wordwrapping to see it happening. The question is: what is the definitive method of getting the viewport width/height?

Comment: Hi Martijn. "a million answers that are all […] wrong" – could you be more precise, please? Why are they wrong, what are they missing?

Comment: Like I said, all existing answers claim to correctly return the viewport size using the above combination of `document.documentElement.clientWidth/Height` and `window.innerWidth/Height` while in fact they return the viewport size *at minimum*. If the document is longer or wider, they'll return that. That makes them wrong.

Comment: Did you make sure your HTML includes a `viewport` tag which avoids any zooming?

Comment: Yep, sure did, as you should be able to see in my pen.